# BackboneJS Search Filter System

Tags: javascript, php, html, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm using Controller to Fetch URL. I need a way to put Parameter in this POST. These Parameters are selected by users on View & Not Stored yet(I dont know how to store)

Currently I managed to 
1) Display & Route The View with search result coming from API
2) Display and refresh the page when someone selects a Filter Option

Problem
1) I got no idea how to record what the users clicked
2) How do i "re-post" so i can get the new set of results
3) I read and say people saying POST Fetch should be done in Model , Conllection is for Store Multiple Models which i don't know in this scenario?

Collections
Jobs.js

```
    define([
        'jquery',
        'underscore',
        'backbone',
        'models/filter'
    ], function($, _, Backbone,JobListFilterModel){
        var Jobs = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            url: function () {
                return 'http://punchgag.com/api/jobs?page='+this.page+''
            },
            page: 1,
            model: JobListFilterModel
        });
        return Jobs;
});
```

Collections Filter.JS

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'models/filter'
], function($, _, Backbone,JobListFilterModel){
    console.log("Loaded");

    var Jobs = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: function () {
            return 'http://punchgag.com/api/jobs?page='+this.page+''
        },
        page: 1,
        model: JobListFilterModel
    });

//    var donuts = new JobListFilterModel;
//    console.log(donuts.get("E"));

    return Jobs;
});
```

Models
Filter.js

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
], function(_, Backbone){
    var JobFilterModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            T: '1',   //Task / Event-based
            PT: '1',  //Part-time
            C: '1',   //Contract
            I: '1'    //Internship
        }
    });
    // Return the model for the module
    return JobFilterModel;
});
```

Models
Job.js

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
], function(_, Backbone){
    var JobModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            name: "Harry Potter"
        }
    });
    // Return the model for the module
    return JobModel;
});
```

Router.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'views/jobs/list',
    'views/jobs/filter'



], function($, _, Backbone, JobListView, JobListFilterView){
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
// Define some URL routes
            'seeker/jobs': 'showJobs',
            '*actions': 'defaultAction'
        },
        initialize: function(attr)
        {
            Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: "/"})
        },
        showJobs: function()
        {
            var view = new JobListView();
            view.$el.appendTo('#bbJobList');
            view.render();
            console.log(view);


            var jobListFilterView = new JobListFilterView();
            jobListFilterView.render()
        },
        defaultAction: function(actions)
        {
            console.info('defaultAction Route');
            console.log('No route:', actions);
        }
    });

    var initialize = function(){

        console.log('Router Initialized');// <- To e sure yout initialize method is called

        var app_router = new AppRouter();
    };
    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
})
```

;

Answer (score 0):

Capturing what a user has done should be completed within a view. For example:

filterView.js

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize: function() {
    _.extend(this, Backbone.Events);
  },

  render: function() {
    // Your normal render routine
    return this;
  },

  events: {
    "submit form": "submit"
  },

  submit: function() {
    var query = $("input[type=search]", this.el).val();
    this.trigger("submit", query);
  }

});

return View;
```

...whatever implements filterView and jobCollection...

```
// Implement our collections, views, etc
var jobCollection = new JobCollection();
var jobsView = new JobsView();
var filterView = new FilterView().render();

// Add listeners on our view
filterView.on("submit", updateJobs);

// Implement the functions for our view (this can be done in a number of ways)
function updateJobs(query) {
  jobCollection.fetch({
    data: {
      query: query
    }
  }).done(function(response) {
    // Technically you could just provide "jobsView.render" to the done() method, but I wanted to be a little more verbose here regarding parameters
    jobsView.render(response);
  });
}
```

Your view is only aware of itself (input structure, etc). The thing that implements the view and collection is the broker between these two modules.

You specify parameters within the `fetch` statement by providing an object which implements a `data` parameter. In this case, we're going to pass the query using the `query` key. `fetch` returns a promise, so once that's done, we return that response to the `jobsView` and pass it to the render function, which should be set up to accept the collection.

`updateJobs` is unaware of the view implementation, all it knows is it expects a query to be included.

This code is not meant to be directly implemented or copy/pasted, but it's meant to provide an outline for how you might accomplish what you're looking to do.